Commands that are \@preamblecmds: definitively not subject to hooks?
The ltcmdhooks-doc reads:

The hooks are not physically present before \begin{document} (i.e., using a command in the preamble will never execute the hook) [...]

Does it mean that commands that are \@preamblecmds are definitively not subject to hooks? The following MCE seems to confirm this, which is a too bad!
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/textbf/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {textbf}
  \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
}
\AddToHook{cmd/makeindex/before}{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {makeindex}
  \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\textbf{Foo}.
\end{document}

(In my actual use case, the \@preamblecmds command I'm interested in is not \makeindex but biblatex's \addbibresource.)

No, it means that the hook code has no effect unless the command is called after \begin{document}.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\typeout{foo-#1-foo}}

\AddToHook{cmd/foo/before}{\typeout{executed hook}}

\foo{x}

\begin{document}

\foo{y}

\end{document}

This will print
foo-x-foo
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./dbadd.aux)
executed hook
foo-y-foo

which complies with the description you give at the beginning of the question.
The \@preamblecmds list has nothing to do with this, as you see.
Note that the same output would be obtained with
\AddToHook{cmd/foo/before}{\typeout{executed hook}}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\typeout{foo-#1-foo}}


(Maybe I was misleading with \@preamblecmds.) My concern precisely is for commands that can't be called after preamble (the \@onlypreamble ones, hence the ones such as \addbibresource): in your example, if you don't call \foo after \begin{document}, the hook never applies.
